# C++ Builder: How to add "Implemented Categories" key to registry?

Tags: com, c++builder, registrykey

I try to implement a COM plugin for a 3rd party program. 
It requires an "implemented categories" key in the windows registry, otherwise it does not find the plugin. The key should be placed here:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/CLSID/<Your CLSID>/Implemented Categories/KEY-TO-BE-REGISTERED
```

I would like to register the key at the time when my COM object (DLL/EXE) is registered.

This key is a very similar GUID like CLSID, LIBID, etc., in the COM world

[Implemented-Categories attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676197.aspx)

But so far I haven't found any solution or description.

C++ Builder made a transition from ATL to DAX a few years ago, so old ATL or Visual Studio references are not really helpful.

So the question is: how can I register an "Implemented Categories" key in C++Builder, in the DAX era, in a straight forward way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike ATL, DAX does not natively support category registrations (see [QC #88043](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=88043)).  However, you can override the virtual `UpdateRegistry()` method in your COM object's implementation class and have it create the necessary Registry key when the `Register` parameter is true.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking exactly for this. I don't know how did i miss it.